# Sending a confirmation link via email on django

Tags: django, django-email

I am trying to send a mail to a user to accept a friend request via a confirmation link in django.

Any help will be appreciated

**view.py**

```
def profile(request,User_id):    
    if form1.is_valid():
        form1 = form1.save(commit=False)
        form1.creator = request.user
        form1.save()
        send_mail('Friend Request', 'You have a friend request.',request.user.email,[form1.friend.email],
                fail_silently=False)
```

**models.py**

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
    RESPONSE_CHOICES = (
    ('Inactive','Inactive'),
    ('Active','Active'),
    )
   response = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=RESPONSE_CHOICES,default='Inactive')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friendship_creator_set")
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friend_set")
```

Comment: My bad. Have you tried anything as yet? If so, share it, tell what went wrong with it and what was expected.

Comment: I am able to send a mail to the other user.....but have no idea how to add a confirmation link

Comment: this is unrelated to the question, but response should probably be a boolean field...

Comment: yea....i corrected that part a while ago....:)

Comment: Nevermind....its done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
send_mail('Confirmation email',
          # this is a link you wanted to
          "http://127.0.0.1:8000%s" % reverse('user_confirm',kwargs={'key': form1.key}),
            request.user.email, [form1.friend.email])
```

I simply tweaked the send_mail() a bit